# Refresh ListAdapter after click on item in actioon bar

Tags: android, button, android-actionbar, refresh

Im frustrated with resfreshing data in listfragment.

1.) proplem:

I tried handle actionbar menu item (refresh button) in fragment to refresh data in list,
but this not working (nothing happened)

```
  @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_refresh:
    ...
```

2.) problem

I have fragment:

```
public class TodoFragment extends ListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Item>>{...}
```

but i have no idea, not found solution, how to refresh data in listfragment

Or how to refresh listfragment from activity (in activity menu buttons working).

Comment: This is a bit cryptic.  Could you post some relevant code from listfragment

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem this way:

```
private TodoFragment newFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    newFragment = new TodoFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.map_fragment, newFragment);
    transaction.commit();

}

 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_refresh:

         newFragment.refreshList();
         return true;

        default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

    //In your fragment

public void refreshList() {
     // Your code
}
```

Comment: i have implemented ActionBar.TabListener and this have implemented methods, which not support v4 :/ here is my activity: http://pastebin.com/un4zGkyK